# PayPal Recurring Payments with express checkout limitations

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I have some questions about recurring payments using express checkout. On your developer web at the recurring payment page is stated:

- `To be able to create a recurring payments profile for the buyer, you must ensure that the buyer's PayPal account includes an active credit card.`
- `You can create a maximum of 10 recurring payments profiles during checkout.`
- `You can increase the profile amount by only 20% in each 180-day interval after you create the profile.`

For the first statement: can you check that the buyer account has an active cc during express checkout? I mean, can you check that programmatically?

The second and third statement: what does that means 10 recurring payments profiles during checkout? 10 profiles totally or 10 profiles at once? If I will sell my subscription to 1000 customers, can I create 1000 recurring payments or the maximum is 10? What about if I set-up a recurring payment using CC instead of express checkout, are there any limitations to how many profiles you can create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Can you check that the buyer account has an active cc during express checkout? I mean, can you check that programmatically?** No, PayPal will take care of this for you.
2. **What does that means 10 recurring payments profiles during checkout? 10 profiles totally or 10 profiles at once?** 10 at one time.  Assuming that you can get the buyer to agree to it, you can set up any number of recurring payments profiles with a single buyer, but you'd have to send them back to PayPal multiple times to approve all of them.
3. **If I will sell my subscription to 1000 customers, can I create 1000 recurring payments or the maximum is 10?** You can create 1000 recurring payments.  There's no limit to the number of recurring payments profiles that you, as the merchant, can establish with your buyers.
4. **What about if I set-up a recurring payment using CC instead of express checkout, are there any limitations to how many profiles you can create?**  Again, no (but keep in mind -- to set up a recurring payment using a credit card -- and not through Express Checkout -- requires you to sign up for Website Payments Pro with Recurring Payments).