# PayPal Recurring Payments with express checkout - 10 payment profiles limitation

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I have a question about recurring payments using PayPal express checkout. On the PayPal developer documentation the recurring payment page states:

- To be able to create a recurring payments profile for the buyer, you
  must ensure that the buyer's PayPal account includes an active credit
  card.
- You can create a maximum of 10 recurring payments profiles
  during checkout.
- You can increase the profile amount by only 20% in
  each 180-day interval after you create the profile.

This previous response ([PayPal Recurring Payments with express checkout limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423211/paypal-recurring-payments-with-express-checkout-limitations)states): What does that means 10 recurring payments profiles during checkout? 10 profiles totally or 10 profiles at once? 10 at one time. Assuming that you can get the buyer to agree to it, you can set up any number of recurring payments profiles with a single buyer, but you'd have to send them back to PayPal multiple times to approve all of them.

**When and how would the PayPal user be prompted to re-authorize additional recurring payments (beyond the initial 10)?**

Comment: If you found any answer for "how would the PayPal user be prompted to re-authorize" then please answer ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928635/paypal-java-sdk-examples-for-recurring-payments?noredirect=1#comment92766529_52928635']

Answer (score 0):

Christi,

I've set up recurring payments with Paypal before. If you get 1000 customers in a day, it will set up 1000 profiles, 1 per each of those customers. They will continue to be billed indefinitely for an endless subscription. I believe the 10 different profiles is per customer if they are buying multiple subscription items at once, I'm not a 100% sure on this, as I only sold 1 subscription product at a time.

Once the profile is created, you can raise your prices by 20% every 180 days. The customer does not have to approve it, however if you raise your prices they will get an email, letting them know about the increase. The customer will then have to make a decision, "do nothing" and the price sticks. Or cancel the subscription.