# Paypal JAVA SDK examples for recurring payments

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a requirement for recurring yearly payment for my services.
and amount of recurring profile will be changed at any time, even before one day of next cycle.

I could not find a proper way to implement a recurring profile in Paypal using Java SDK.

Paypal document shows I need to create Plan and Agreement, Then buyer needs to approve this [Agreement](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-agreement/#create-billing-agreement-attribute-object). and from the response I got token, which I use as 
I following below step:

1. Create Plan, which returns me planId.
2. Make plan Active by generated planId.
3. Prepare Agreement object with start date and description, provide plan id to the agreement object. Which return URL for agreement.
4. Buyer will redirect to Paypal, after the success, it will return me Token.
   then execute the agreement with return token.

Now profile is getting generated in buyer account, but how can I update it every time when I change the amount?

**I found detail as you can not increase the amount of more than 20% within 180 days.**

So I need to delete existing profile and recreate the new one with a new amount every time. so does user need to pay and Agree for it every time?

Is there any step by step document? Any help is welcome.

Comment: I use the C# API so it's different in the code. But what we do is make a call to authorize payment and get back a token. And we then pass that token for all subsequent charges. The token is good for a year.

Comment: " The token is good for a year." this word should make my day. I will check this. hope this will work.

Comment: @DavidThielen no luck with the existing token. profile not getting updated. and it returns me old profile detail always with an old token. If possible share c# code for update portion only. it might help me. Thanks for your comment